# MENU : La flecha no cambia hacia abajo de nuevo

Tags: jquery, html, css

Aqui consigo que la flecha apunte hacia arriba

```js
 $('.menu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle();
 });

$(".sidebar-nav > li.menu > a").click(function(){
  
   if($(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').hasClass('in')){
   //DOWN
   $(this).css('background-image','url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png")');
   }else{
       //UP
    $(this).css('background-image','url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHAUP16ba0.png")');
   }   
  }
 );
```

```css
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul li .menu-sub {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a {
    background-image: url(https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 110px;
    background-position-y: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu </a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Otras Listas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contenidos del sitio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

faltaria es que la flecha del dropdown cambie de direccion hacia abajo

Comment: Me equivoque, gracias por editar. xD

Comment: HAHAH Nada, la proxima vez recuerda la funcion de introducir codigo y explica un poco mejor hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te voy a poner una solución que simplifica un poco el asunto: la idea es que la flecha dependa de una clase definida por ti, entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir/quitar la clase cuando el menú esté activo (usando `toggleClass`).

Por ejemplo:

```js
$('.menu').click(function(){
  $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul li .menu-sub {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a {
    background-image: url(https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 110px;
    background-position-y: 7px;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li.active > a {
  background-image: url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHAUP16ba0.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu </a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Otras Listas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contenidos del sitio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

Otra opción sería usar sólo CSS, mostrando el submenú dependiendo del foco del enlace dentro del menú (seleccionado con `:focus` y el selector de "hermano" `~`)

Algo como esto:

```css
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul li .menu-sub {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:0px;
    transition: all 0.6s;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a {
    background-image: url(https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 110px;
    background-position-y: 7px;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-image: url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHAUP16ba0.png");
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a:focus ~ .menu-sub {
  max-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu </a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Otras Listas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contenidos del sitio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Pero esta solución plantea algunos problemas:

- Funciona mejor si conoces la altura del submenú, algo que no siempre vas a saber si es dinámico (podrías poner un valor alto, pero entonces se verá como si hubiese un retraso).
- El menú no se cierra cuando pulsas en "menu" cuando está abierto (si se cerrará si pulsas fuera del menú o en otra opción).

Answer (score 4):

Realmente estas realizando la comprobación con una clase `in` la cual no le agregas nunca.

Tendrías que agregar o quitar la clase `in` con los métodos:

```
$(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').removeClass('in'); 
$(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').addClass('in');
```

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
$('.menu').click(function(){
     $(this).children('.menu-sub').slideToggle();
});

$(".sidebar-nav > li.menu > a").click(function(){
    if($(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').hasClass('in')){
        //DOWN
 $(this).css('background-image','url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png")'); 
        $(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').removeClass('in'); 
    }else{
       //UP
 $(this).css('background-image','url("https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHAUP16ba0.png")');
        $(this).siblings('ul.menu-sub').addClass('in'); 
    }   
});
```

```css
.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
}

ul li .menu-sub {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

ul.sidebar-nav > li > a {
    background-image: url(https://i.dmtinc.cl/i/2017/01/05/icon__FLECHA24528.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 110px;
    background-position-y: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li class="menu">
            <a href="#">Menu </a>
            <ul class="menu-sub">
                <li><a href="#">Otras Listas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contenidos del sitio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: estaba a punto de dar a enter v.v xDD pero na, mi solucion era fea, usando una booleana para controlar la imagen, en vez de los hijos

Comment: @Error404 Gracias , gracias , gracias gracias